# PyobjC : Application throwing an error if we shutdown Mac

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc

I am running a simple pyobj c app. However, if I try to shutdown the mac while the app is running, it does not close gracefully like the other apps. I noticed that if I comment out the line `AppHelper.runEventLoop()`, there is no issue. How do I get the eventloop to terminate gracefully in case the user tries to restart/shutdown the Mac before quitting the application.

Answer (score 0):

The event loop should self terminate when the application has been asked to terminate (provided something isnt blocking the "terminate" request).

Your problem certainly has nothing to do with `AppHelper.runEventLoop()` the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/api/module-PyObjCTools.AppHelper.html) clearly states that this **does not** return, unless an exception is thrown.

You must have something setup in place that is blocking the application from terminating. (unsaved document?, modal window?)